# AngularJS on ng-dblclick change input[text]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that is populated with ngRepeat and I have a input[text] where you can filter the table.

This works fine but now I came up with the idea to have the possibility to double-click on an element in the table and add the text to the search input[text] so the filter is applied straight when you double-click on the text.

Unfortunately it does not work as expected.
I have done this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." data-ng-model="userinput" />
<p data-ng-dblclick="userinput='query'">Double click to use query to search</p>
```

And in the ngRepeat I use the ng-model "userinput" to filter but the value of the text input is not changing.

I also tried to specify the model "userinput" as variable in the controller and then change it per function but it is not working.

Is there something I'm missing?

Normally I would change the variable in the controller and it should automatically change the text input since it uses this variable as model. Then with this it should change the filter too but nothing happens.

***WORKING***

**Code ngRepeat**

```
 <tr data-ng-repeat="dat in data | filter: userInput | filter: tsSelect | filter: advSelect |  filter: checkedFilter | orderBy: ['client', 'ssrstatus'] | limitTo: totalDisplay" id="{{ dat.bannerid }}"> <!-- | unique: 'bannerid' | filter: errorSelect| -->
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checked" data-ng-model="dat.checked" data-ng-change="updateCheckedStatus(dat._id['$id'], dat.checked)">
    <label for="checked">Checked</label>
</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.clientid)">{{ dat.clientid }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.client)" class="txtleft">{{ dat.client }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.tsengineer)">{{ dat.tsengineer }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.bannerid)">{{ dat.bannerid }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.bannertype)" class="txtleft">{{ dat.bannertype }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.width + 'x' + dat.height)">{{ dat.width == 0 ? 0 : dat.width - 50 }}x{{ dat.height == 0 ? 0 : dat.height - 50 }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.ssrstatus)" class="txtleft">{{ dat.ssrstatus }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.datebegin)">{{ dat.datebegin }}</td>
<td data-ng-dblclick="search(dat.dateupdated)">{{ dat.dateupdated }}</td>
<td>
    <button class="preview {{ dat.bannerid }}" data-ng-click="showPreview(dat.bannerid, dat.clicktotestbanner, dat.width, dat.height)"></button>
</td>
<!-- <td id="{{ dat.bannerid }}" class="banner-preview"></td> -->
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.userInput = "";
$scope.search = function(query){
    $scope.userInput = query;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant code, where is your ng-repeat for example.

Comment: Sorry, just added it, thought it was clear but of course it is better like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because of your `userinput='query'` evaluated inside `ng-repeat`.

Let's name your outer scope "scopeA". The `ng-model="userinput"` of the search input would be referencing `scopeA.userinput`.

As we know, a new scope is created for every `ng-repeat` items. If you run `userinput='query'` in one of these scopes (name it scopeB), you would be assigning `'query'` to `scopeB.userinput` instead of `scopeA.userinput`.

In this situation, scopeB is likely to be a child of scopeA. If you use `angular-batarang` Chrome extension to have a look at the scope tree, you would find both scopes to have `userinput` field.

One solution would be to use a function to assigning value to userinput instead of `ng-dblclick` expression. Like:

```
<p data-ng-dblclick="setUserinput('query')">Double click to use query to search</p>
```

And add a function `setUserinput` to your scope:

```
$scope.setUserinput = function(newValue) {
    $scope.userinput = newValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution :) The trick was to use the function instead of changing the variable of the $scope. It didn't work when I tried but I guess I had a careless mistake